# Cannot create column with type "TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE" in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

when i tried to create a column with the data type "TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE" in postgresql
it's always created in the database as "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE" , so is there's any workarounds or solutions for this problem ?

```
<addColumn tableName="myTable">
            <column name="date_added" type="TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
 </addColumn>
```

btw, this issue is on jira:
http://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-877

Comment: Keep in mind Liquibase is interpreting XML tags into PostgreSQL SQL commands. To be sure what SQL is being executed run Liquibase with the updateSQL option to see what the actual SQL being generated is.

Comment: Can't you fix this bug in Liquibase? That's where the real problem is, Liquibase creates the wrong SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this page http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/sql_format.html.   just manually type in the needed SQL exactly how you want it if you use the SQL format with Liquibase.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of using the  tag and switch completely from XML to sql, you could modify the resulting generated SQL using the  tag which is valid across the whole changeset: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/modify_sql.html

for example in your case you would have this:

```
<modifySql dbms="postgresql">
    <replace replace="WITH" with="WITHOUT"/>
</modifySql>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works great. 
One tip: The modifySql element goes inside the changeSet element and works across the whole changeSet. However, it was valid only if I place the modifySql element inside but at the end of the changeSet.
And the current link is http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/modify_sql.html

Answer (score 2):

After a long time since this query, liquibase team has already corrected this problem and now you can add following column type:

```xml
<column name="created_at" type="TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE">
    <constraints nullable="true"/>
</column>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the <sql> tag to create the exact SQL you are wanting if liquibase is generating the wrong SQL for you.

Comment: @sword101 I think this is what you need to look at http://www.liquibase.org/manual/custom_sql.

Comment: @StarShip3000 Yes, I forgot to escape the angle brackets around the sql tag and so it didn't show. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @magomarcelo you can also write [modifysql](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/modify_sql.html) as a YAML.
The following example ignores unsigned in postgresql:

```
- modifySql:
    dbms: postgresql
    replace:
      replace: unsigned
      with: default 0
```